# How can you call a function from within a constructor when the contractor is defined before he function definition?

Tags: object-oriented, class-design, memory

I have gone through multiple posts but am unable to find an answer to my very basic question on classes and so asking it here, it would be great if someone could shed some light on this topic-

I have a twofold question which is generic to any OOP language-

1)When a class is instantiated what are the exact steps that take place and how is memory allocated to the member functions and the attributes of the class and in what order? As in is memory first allocate to the member functions of the class or the attributes of the class?

2)I understand that it is possible to call functions of a class from within the constructor of the class, but I am unable to understand how this is possible and how the constructor knows of the existence of the function being called as the function being called is defined after the constructor and according to my understanding when instantiating a class the constructor is the first function that is called and executed so this would mean that the other member functions of the class have still not been allocated any memory and do not exist. Is my understanding clear here or am I missing something?

Some help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Not sure why the downvotes, this isn’t about specific code and has a concise, definitive answer...

Comment: @Telastyn; this question has several issues. It starts with a false premise ( "generic to any OOP language"), and it asks things which don't make any sense for lots of languages (language implementations), and it conflates calling order with definition order, which shows a lack of basic research. All in all, it gives a very confused impression.

Comment: About your second question - again, the details are implementation dependent, but there are two aspects to this. First, a class is just a blueprint, so the compiler can generate code for all of it before any of the code is actually executed; if something calls something else declared later on, you can just put a temp there, then go back an update the address. So the code for all the functions exists before any object is created - they are actually shared between instances.

Comment: So, that leads me to the second point - methods being owned by the objects is a high-level illusion. They typically take instance data as an extra parameter. The constructor creates a plain data structure, and adds some extra stuff to it (e.g. a vtable) to make OOP work; after that, it can call other methods - it'll just pass them that data. It then places this data struct somewhere in memory, and hands you a variable. At the language level, you can only treat it as an object - you can't see what the compiler actually placed in there. It's probably just a memory address.

Answer (score 2):

> what are the exact steps that take place and how is memory allocated to the member functions and the attributes of the class and in what order?

This is language (and in some cases, implementation) specific. In a fair number of languages (e.g. Python, JavaScript), the allocation of memory is not a concept which is exposed by the language so your question doesn't really make sense.

> member functions of the class have still not been allocated any memory

Even in a language where the concept of allocating memory makes sense (say, C++), member functions are not allocated memory. They are "just" a function which happens to take the object as a (hidden) parameter, and exist just once in memory, no matter how many instances of the object exists.

Comment: Yes i understand and agree with your points above but this does not answer the second questions i have asked where in when we call a function from within the constructor why do i not get any error? Does the function being called already exist? If so how?

Comment: @CodingNewbie - Philip Kendall answers that in the second part of the answer. Functions just exist in the exe/dll - they exist as soon as your code is written (or compiled depending on the language). There are a few languages where the function is created with the instance, but those languages are very rare. That said, you _do_ sometimes get errors when you call a member function from a constructor. Subclasses usually aren’t instantiated yet, and accessing fields defined there will either fail or return null/nothing; calling virtual functions will usually not do what you expect.

Comment: @Telastyn Thanks for your response but if we consider the case of just C++ under normal circumstances that is without using classes if i called a function before defining it or at least declaring it i would get an error/warning when i execute the code but i don't get the same warning/error in the case of calling functions before declaration/definition in the constructor of a class, this confuses me.

Comment: @CodingNewbie: you'd get an error when _compiling_ the code. Just consider that the compiler reads over class definitions twice: once to see all functions declared, and a second time to actually do the compilation with that knowledge. All this is done at compile time (for C++), before the program executes.

Comment: More generally, you seem a bit confused between compiling, linking and execution. A program where a function (either a member function or a free function) isn't declared may fail to compile depending on your settings. A program where a function isn't defined will fail to link. In neither case will you be able to execute the code, because it isn't a valid program.

Comment: @CodingNewbie: without classes, in C and C++ functions can be called in code which is placed before their definition by using forward declations. And the class declaration in a header file of a C++ class works as a forward declaration as well. Other programming languages like C# or Java don't impose any restriction between definition and calling order.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have a basic misunderstanding of how instantiation works and how a program goes from human-readable text to a format that can be executed by a processor.

First, when a source file with a class in it is read by a compiler or interpreter, the entire class is read and converted to a data structure that can be used by either the runtime environment or the interpreter when the class gets instantiated. At this time, the executable memory for the methods of the class is set aside.

Secondly, when the execution reaches the point where the class needs to be instantiated, memory is reserved for the instance members and for the administration of exactly which methods belong to that instance.

> 1. When a class is instantiated what are the exact steps that take place and how is memory allocated to the member functions and the attributes of the class and in what order? As in is memory first allocate to the member functions of the class or the attributes of the class?

The exact steps taken depend on the language in question, but invariably the member functions are "allocated" way before the class is instantiated.

> 2. I understand that it is possible to call functions of a class from within the constructor of the class, but I am unable to understand how this is possible and how the constructor knows of the existence of the function being called as the function being called is defined after the constructor and according to my understanding when instantiating a class the constructor is the first function that is called and executed so this would mean that the other member functions of the class have still not been allocated any memory and do not exist. Is my understanding clear here or am I missing something?

Most OOP languages are designed such that first a class is read in its entirety, including all member functions and after that the references to other member functions are resolved. That way, the order in which the member functions appear within the class' definition does not affect which member function cal call which other member functions. This is all done before the execution reaches the point where the class is instantiated the first time.